# Docker / Postgres: Mounting an existing database within a dockerized Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

So I'm having a problem mounting an existing set of data for Docker Postgres that I cannot figure out for the life of me. Here's my docker compose file.

```
version: '2'
    services:
      postgresql:
        image: postgres:9.5
        environment:
          - PGDATA=/data 
        ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - ~/.postgresql:/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: sbt/sbt run
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - '9001:9001'
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
```

Here's the error I see

```
ostgresql_1 | FATAL:  data directory "/data" has wrong ownership
postgresql_1 | HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
```

Does anyone have any clue how to fix it? Thank you

PS I am using Docker Machine through OSX if that makes a difference in this problem.

Comment: You mean add a User in the existing db? Or write my own Docker Postgres image using the official as a base with the command you referenced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear. I think the container runs postgres with user `postgres` which has a uid/gid of `999` (see https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/3f8e9784438c8fe54f831c301a45f4d55f6fa453/9.5/Dockerfile line 5). You need to `chown` your host data folder to a user with the same `uid`.

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know about the uid thing, let me try and fix that and get back to you